# Triangle-shaped points appear more transparent than the circular points

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

As I have asked in the [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71740163/use-guides-to-overwrite-the-second-legend-in-the-figure/71740284#71740284), I'm trying to plot curves varying according to different quantities, and I am mapping these quantities to the color and shape aesthetics.

However, when I do that, the dots having triangle shape look more transparent than the circular dots.

How can I solve this issue?

PS: I'm using the same code & dataset I have given in the linked question.

[image]

Comment: Just from a look at the code in your old question that is probably the case because of overplotting, i.e. your points look less transparent because many points are plotted on top of each other.

Comment: @stefan if I compare the circular points and the triangular ones, the former is more *overlappingly* plotted I would say, so I can't how overplotting can cause this.

Comment: Agreed with stefan. Looking at the plot above, you can see rare examples where circles are as transparent as triangles, so they *do* occur. Overplotting *is* plotting overlapping points, and it smells* wrong that this overlap appears exact for many circle points. \* If you have the chance, you should ask the person who generated the data why these apparent duplicates are in the data.

Comment: @teunbrand please see the updated figure. I'm the one who plots these figures and even if I bin the data the issue persists.

Comment: @stefan see the updated figure